# I'm looking for how to find the HTML code of a Podio webform that I can make custom CSS for this form

Tags: html, css, podio

I am new to Podio and I'm experiencing some issues trying to customize the CSS of my webforms. Is there anyway to see the HTML of a webform? And if there is, how do I do so? (I really want to see the HTML code so I can find the correct elements/classes to call with my CSS)

If there is no way to see the HTML code of a webform, could I please just get some guidelines on how to use CSS and what classes/elements to call or how they should be called?

I tried to get my submit button to have a specific color and font using this code below but it hasn't worked.

```
input[type=text] {
color: #c90d00;
font-family: "PT Serif", serif;
}


button[type=”submit”] {
color: #8224e3;
font-family: "PT Serif", serif;
}
```

There are no visible results

Comment: most probably `Ctrl + U` will give the source html

Comment: Depending on browser you can right click on any HTML element and click "inspect element" in the menu. From there you can play around with the css to see what works. After you are done, copy the changed css to your css-file